# Pop-up modal only works on first button in array

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, popup

I'm trying to implement a pop up modal for a real estate website I'm designing. When you enter the Agents page, each agent has their own personal bio and a "contact" card. When selecting the contact card a pop-up modal appears and grey's out the background. I managed to implement the modal but it's only working on the first button in the array of 9. I know this has something to do with unique ID's but I'm not entirely sure how to execute it. Any  advice would be helpful.

- J. Hart

```
// Agent bio:

<section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="cardB">                    
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/H8By9Ns.jpg" alt="Pondra Bowen" class="center-cardB" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                <div class="container">
               "Agent's personal information redacted"
    <p><button id="myBtn" class="rounded">Contact</button></p>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<section>



// The modal
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  // Modal Content
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="flex">
        <div id="form-container">
            <h3>Contact Form</h3>
            <form>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" />

                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" />

                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" id="subject" />

                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Write your message here..."></textarea>

                <button class="rounded">Send Message</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</section>




<script>

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: where is your other array element ? can you create jsfiddle ? @joel-hart

Comment: Joel Hart, I've answered. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you do this:

`var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");` and presumably you only have 1 id called `myBtn` or if you do have more then it will call just the first one it finds every time

you should change the approach. store all the users in an array of objects, with a unique id. `.map` over this array to show all the users. and then when you click on one, pass in the `ID` as an argument. then use that `id` to filter the array to show the relevant stuff. simplified example below

```
const users = [
   {id: 1, name: 'Tom', email: 'tom@test.com},
   {id: 2, name: 'Sam', email: 'sametest.com},
]
```

then map over them to render them

```
users.map((user) => 
   <div onClick={() => renderModalForCorrectUser(user.id)>
     <div> {user.name} </div>
     <div> {user.email} </div>
   </div>
```

then

```
function renderModalForCorrectUser(id) {
    //find the correct user by id
    // then do the opening of the modal by passing in the relevant users details
}
```

Comment: @JoelHart good to know! can you upvote and mark question as correct. thank you!

Comment: I did upvote but I have less than 15 reputation so it won't display publicly. And thank you again!